# Is this set compact? Fixed point problem

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the prelim question.

Let $X\subseteq C^{\infty}([0,1])$ be uniformly bounded and equicontinuous such that $f\in X\implies f'\in X$. Assume that $||f'-g'||_{\infty}\leq \frac{1}{2}||f-g||_{\infty}$. Show there is a sequence $f_n$ in $X$ that converges uniformly to $Ce^x$ for some constant $C$.

Now I thought I could show this by using the fact that the derivative map on this space is a strict contraction, and so repeating the proof of the Banach contraction theorem should give the result. However, $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ with this norm is not complete, so this idea might not work.

Also, this uniformly bounded and equicontinuous condition makes me think there's some kind of compactness/Arzela-Ascoli argument here, but I don't see how.

Comment: The necessary property of $X$ being non-empty is omitted, is there any other property of $X$ missing?

Comment: If $X$ is non-empty, then take $f\in X$. Using the condition, the sequence $f^{(n)}$ converges uniformly. Let $f$ be the limit. The sequence of derivatives $(f^{(n)})'$ is just the shifted sequence $f^{(n+1)}$, which converges uniformly. Therefore, $f'$ exists and is the limit of $f^{(n+1)}$. It follows also that $f'=f$.

Comment: What is the sequence $f_n$ you're referring to?

Comment: Successive derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Ok, so you're fixing an arbitrary $f\in X$ and letting $f_n=D^nf$. Now in the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem, you show this sequence is Cauchy. Since $C^{\infty}$ is not complete with this norm, I think this doesn't work. So you're suggesting that $f_n$ converges uniformly by some compactness argument?

Comment: If $X$ were also closed in $C^{\infty}\subset C^0$, the continuous functions, I can see how you could use Arzela Ascoli to find a uniformly convergent subsequence. But without knowing $X$ is closed, I don't see why this is true

Comment: 'converges uniformly' has an specific definition, convergence in $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, which is what I am using. You don't need that $X$ is closed, since you don't need to show that the limit is inside $X$.

Comment: How do you know $f_n$ converges to some $f\in X$ in this norm?

Comment: It is a Cauchy sequence: $\|f^{(m)}-f^{(n)}\|_\infty\leq \sum_{k=n}^{m}2^{-k}\|f-f'\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$ for $n,m$ large.

Comment: Right, but $C^{\infty}([0,1])$ is not complete in this norm.

Comment: So what? You take the limit, and then prove that it is smooth as I did above.

Comment: Ah, wait I see what you mean. You're using the fact that $C^0$, not $C^{\infty}$ is complete in this norm

Comment: I think your argument makes sense to me, thank you. If you have time,  could you comment on the equicontinuous and uniformly bounded condition? You're using completeness of $C^0$, not compactness of $X$, correct? So why are those conditions given?

Comment: Yes. You just the uniform limit. Then by the properties of the sequence you show that the limit is differentiable and that it satisfies $f'=f$. $f=Ce^x$ follows from there, and smoothness, nobody care about smoothness since the problem asks to show that there is a sequence that converges uniformly to $Ce^x$.

Comment: I have no idea. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: It came from a preliminary exam, so I thought maybe there was some compactness argument that could be used, but maybe not